# Command to delete all files older than a given time and log what it does

Tags: linux, bash, unix, find, exec

I've been struggling with this for a while and after lots of searching decided it's time for help from an expert.

I've trying to remove all file in the dir `/filestodelete` and make a note of them in the file `/something/deletions.log` and so far I've come up with:

```
find /filestodelete -mtime +93 -exec sh -c 'rm -rfv {}' > "/something/deletions.log"
```

When I try to run this, the error received is:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

(I've put the /something/deletions.log in quotes as it might actually have spaces in it - it is called by another bash script).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find is complaining because it's missing a `\;` or `+` at the end.

```
find /filestodelete -mtime +93 -exec sh -c 'rm -rfv {}' > "/something/deletions.log" \;
```

There's no real need for the `sh` sub-shell:

```
find /filestodelete -mtime +93 -exec rm -rfv {} + > /something/deletions.log
```

Comment: Thanks. I went for the version without the sub shell. I only originally started to use one to get around error messages about "ambiguous redirect" but it was the + missing all along! Thanks again.